# Jquery: How to bind an event to element that has a sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, selector

I'm looking to bind a change event to an input element, but only if its next sibling is a select element, so that when the input value changes, if it matches any of the options in the select element, then that option will be selected.  I know I can just bind the event to all the inputs and then check if each of them has a select sibling, but that is more computationally expensive, so I'd rather not do that.  Any ideas?

This is what I am currently using:

```
$("input").each(function () {
    var elmt = $(this);
    if (!elmt.next("select")) {
        return;
    }
    elmt.on("change", function () {
        if (elmt.next("select").has("option[value='"+elmt.val()+"']")) {
            elmt.next("select").val(elmt.val());
        }
        else {
            elmt.next("select").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `I know I can just bind the event to all the inputs and then check if each of them has a select sibling` -- if you know how to do that, then just do the checking before the binding instead, right?

Comment: For a small number of inputs (already should be greatly reduced), the "computationally expensive" (vs. some 'faster method') is likely not relevant.

Comment: @TKol, yes, that would be a better option than binding first, but it would still require looping over all the input elements first, rather than just using a selector.  But that is the option I will go with if there is not another way.

Comment: Why 'loop over all elements' any more than any other binding (or deferred binding) method? The DOM element is available, and the initial pass is already filtered to a (likely) small subset of all elements.

Comment: Selector with this type of check is going to end up doing the same looping since there is no selector that can can do the check with sibling and refer to itself.

Comment: There is an adjacent sibling selector, but it can only be used to select the next element I believe, not the previous one.

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, I figured as much, but I would still rather leave it up to the selector to do the looping than do it myself, in case there are any unknown browser optimizations that it can take advantage of, like if the browser caches certain selector results on the page or indexes them or something, idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe you jquery .prev

```
$('inputs + select').prev().on(...);
```

give it a try

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!